# How to limit xgboost execution time?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

How to limit xgboost execution time (for example, I have a 'computational budget' 1 hour in cluster)? Also is it possible to limit xgboost in number of rounds?

Comment: To clarify, you're looking to set the number of rounds based on how long it would take to execute them?

Comment: @dataprincess No, it's separate questions.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, if you're directly calling [`xgboost.train`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.training) function, which is used by `XGBModel.fit` under the hood. This function has a `num_boost_round` parameter (to limit the number of boosting rounds) and `callbacks` parameter that you can use to check the running time and raise an `EarlyStopException` if needed. Of course, you can't stop in the middle of iteration, but in `time_limit - delta` minutes.

Unfortunately, `XGBModel` (and correspondingly `XGBRegressor` and `XGBClassifier`) API doesn't allow to pass the callbacks through, so you'll have to refactor your code to a low-level API:

```
params = {'eval_metric': True, ...}
trainDmatrix = DMatrix(X, label=y)
train(params, trainDmatrix, num_boost_round=10, callbacks=[callback])
```